# Access files of folder shared publicly in google drive without login

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have one requirement in which user will upload music files in a folder of google drive and make it public.

All other users will download/view files without logging in for "Google Drive" as its public.

I have used below code to get list of file from shared folder id,

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents and trashed=false", folderId];

self.driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFileList *files, NSError *error)
{
        if (error == nil)
        {
          NSLog(@"Files==%@",files.items);
        }
        else
        {
          NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
 }];
```

But getting error "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

If folder is already public then why login is required?

Comment: you still need to apply a API key to requests even if its public data or you are going to be lumped into the group of unauthenticated requests with everyone else.  The limit gets used up fast.   Applying a public API key will inform Google that its your application making the request and you wont have to worry about any quota other then the main drive quota.

Comment: @DaImTo That's what I needed. Its working. Another question if lots of audio files are there and people are streaming them then will it create any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't.  but double check in the quota section on Google developer console set the per user quota as high as it will let you use the penile thing.

Answer (score 0):

Google changed somethings about a year ago they want you to always identify your application even if you are requesting public data.    If you don't identify your application you get lumped into a huge pool of other people not identifying their application and you all run under the same quota.   As you can guess this quota gets used up quite fast I suspect Google has forced it to be very low to force us to identify our applications

Applying a public API key will inform Google that its your application making the request and you wont have to worry about any quota other then the main drive quota.

Set the per user quota as high as you can in Google developer console I cant remember how high you can set it.

I am not an IOS developer so cant help with any code on how to apply a API key to your request.